# Accessing a GUI element from a (sub-) class not defining it in Python / PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a GUI created by Qt Designer. One element ("screenshot") is used as a placeholder for another class definition. It's Python code translation looks like so:

```
...

class Ui_endomess(object):

    def setupUi(self, endomess):
        ...
        self.screenshot = screenshot(self.centralwidget)
        ...        

from screenshot import screenshot
```

The "screenshot" class looks like so:

```
...
class screenshot(QGraphicsView):
... 
    def some_function(self):
        ...
```

Both are used by a main script with the following stucture:

```
...
from endomess_ui import Ui_endomess
...

class endomess(QMainWindow, Ui_endomess):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
    ...

def main(argv):
    app = QApplication(argv, True)
    wnd = endomess()
    wnd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Of course, I can manipulate GUI object from within the "endomess" class like so:

```
self.calibrateButton.setEnabled(True)
```

What I want to do is manipulate GUI elements from a function within the "screenshot" class. I messed around with "global" calls, but I just don't know how to do it. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The qt-way would be to define a signal in your `screenshot` class and connect that to a slot in your `endomess` class which can then perform the modifications.

From within the `screenshot` class you may also be able to access the object as `self.parent().parent()` (self.parent() should be the `centralWidget`, and that's parent the `endomess` instance), but this may break if something in your hierarchy changes.